# Dependency Injection disadvantages

Tags: dependency-injection

Dependency Injection design pattern is said to be helpful for loose coupling, however I cannot understand how it can be achieved since the calling object has to pass the dependencies in the constructor to the service?

Please explain?

Comment: Good question, though not for StackOverflow. Here questions are expected to be very specific, not about general patterns or principals. I think you should ask this over on https://programmers.stackexchange.com/

Comment: @MarnixvanValen this question is a poor fit for Programmers - it would be quickly voted down and closed over there, see http://meta.programmers.stackexchange.com/questions/6483/why-was-my-question-closed-or-down-voted/6489#6489 Recommended reading: **[What goes on Programmers.SE? A guide for Stack Overflow](http://meta.programmers.stackexchange.com/q/7182/31260)**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I cannot understand how it can be achieved since the calling object has to pass the dependencies in the constructor to the service?

The calling object **does not** have to pass the dependencies in the constructor of the service.

The calling object will have the an implementation of the service injected into its constructor like this:

```
public class CallingObject
{
    private readonly IService m_Service;

    public CallingObject(IService service)
    {
        m_Service = service;
    }

    public void DoSomething()
    {
        m_Service.AskForService();
    }
}
```

The entity that is responsible for wiring all objects together is the [composition root](http://blog.ploeh.dk/2011/07/28/CompositionRoot/).

So its the composition root that has to pass the dependencies into the constructor to the service.

Answer (score 1):

The only disadvantage I found is that highlights design problems and causes many programmers to blame dependency injection for the design problems.

I'm sure that Krzysztof Koźmic can explain it better than me. Please read [this](http://kozmic.net/2012/10/23/ioc-container-solves-a-problem-you-might-not-have-but-its-a-nice-problem-to-have/).

Comment: Can you please explain,what does that mean?

Comment: @phanishm: You should read the linked article. That article describes exactly what jlvaquero means.